# Is there any way to do a Fluent BQL equivalent of PXSelector that u know of?

Tags: acumatica

I wanted to change a PXSelector of a field to Fluent BQL syntax if possible in order to include a subquery.  Is there any way to do a Fluent BQL equivalent of PXSelector that u know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted an example from Acumatica source code on another forum which showed me how to do it.  Here it is:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(SearchFor<CSAttributeGroup.attributeID>.
Where<CSAttributeGroup.entityClassID.
      IsEqual<PX.Data.BQL.RTrim<Use<itemClassID.FromCurrent>.AsString>>.
And<CSAttributeGroup.entityType.IsEqual<Common.Constants.DACName<InventoryItem>>>.
And<CSAttributeGroup.attributeCategory.
    IsEqual<CSAttributeGroup.attributeCategory.variant>>.
And<CSAttributeGroup.attributeID.
    IsNotEqual<defaultRowMatrixAttributeID.FromCurrent>.
    Or<defaultRowMatrixAttributeID.FromCurrent.IsNull>>>),
typeof(CSAttributeGroup.attributeID), 
DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeGroup.description))]
```

Answer (score 1):

The FBQL equivalent of PXSelector is this:

```
SelectFrom<SOOrder>.SearchFor<SOOrder.OrderNbr>
```

or this:

```
SearchFor<SOOrder.OrderNbr>.SelectFrom<SOOrder>
```

You can find more details here: https://www.acumatica.com/media/2019/07/2019-Acumatica-DevCon-F-BQL.pdf

Comment: I've seen the article you reference, but there were not good examples.  Someone posted a good example that I'll post as the answer below.